# Technical explanation behind setting zoom level to 100% for IE Driver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

could someone let me know the technical reasons of why IE Driver requires the zoom level settings to be 100%.

Comment: Hopefully these kinds of things will become less of an issue if Microsoft ever take up the maintenance of the IEDriver

Answer (score 1):

Zoom level needs to be set to 100% so that the native mouse events get the correct coordinates. From this I would assume that if I'm testing mouse related functionality at non 100% zoom levels then it might not work or work erratically because your not certain the mouse it at the correct coordinates. Never tried this so not sure.

This is a known issue 4488 I believe which isn't going to be fixed - there is a workaround; if you think your site can be tested at no 100% setting, which is to use the ignoreZoomSetting capability so that the IEDriver ignores this check. You can then perhaps set zoom by sending key combinations to adjust the zoom level as required?